# Dates go missing when I add additional items

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have a strange situation. When I fill in the date field and click the `autoform-add-item` button the date data disappears but the qualification field data doesn't. The only way to keep the date field entry is to submit the form. Any thoughts.

Path: `dbExample`

```
"profile": {
    "CV": {
      "education": [
        {
          "qualification": "Arts Degree",
          "startDate": "2009-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "endDate": "2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
          "qualification": "Science Degree",
          "startDate": "2007-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "endDate": "2008-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Path: `autoform.html`

```
<template name="education">
{{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" id="educationForm" doc=currentUser type="update"}}

    {{> afQuickField name='profile.CV.education'}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Update</button>
{{/autoForm}}   
</template>
```

Path: `Schema.js`

```
Schema.Education = new SimpleSchema({
    qualification: {
        type: String,  
        optional: true    
    },
    type: Date,  
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
        "data-date-autoclose": "true",
        datePickerOptions: {
            format: "M yyyy",
            startView: "months",
            minViewMode: "months"
        }
    }    
},
endDate: {
    type: Date,  
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
        "data-date-autoclose": "true",
        datePickerOptions: {
            format: "M yyyy",
            startView: "months",
            minViewMode: "months"
        }
    }    
},
});

    Schema.CV = new SimpleSchema({
        education: {
            type: [Schema.Education],
            optional: true
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Meteor.users" id="educationForm" doc=currentUser type="update"}}
    {{#afEachArrayItem name="profile.CV.education"}}
        {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.qualification}}  
        {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.startDate}}
        {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.endDate}}
    {{/afEachArrayItem}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Autoform can't handle arrays of objects by default with quick field, so you need to construct it more manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion unfortantly that didn't fix the problem. I've updated the schema to contain the bootstrap info I have which was missing before. I've also created another test to replicate the problem and the issue disappears. I'm a noob, how do I go about debugging this. There's no erros in console or anything so I'm a little stumped.

Comment: Ok, so it's actually something to do with the aldeed:autoform-bs-datepicker if I remove type: "bootstrap-datepicker" and use the chrome browser date picker the problem disappears. I need a datepicker for old browsers and so I can remove the day and just have month year. Is there a way to fix this?